# SWF to FLV converter

Tags: video, conversion, flash, flv, swf

Is there any freeware SWFL to FLV converter? or avi would be fine as well. Could not find any so far.

Comment: SWFL? (15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) can do it.

> No trial or evaluation. It's free to
>   download and free to use the fully
>   working version.
>
> SUPER © does not require any
>   additional external codecs to be
>   installed.
>   Necessary codecs are built in!

Comment: Have you actually used Super (C)?

Comment: I was using it for conversion purposes. I had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is '[`FLV-Info`](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/FLV-Info/)' at Perl CPAN.

> [**swf2flv**](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/FLV-Info/bin/swf2flv) Transform a video SWF into an FLV
>
> With respect to video and audio content, FLV and SWF files have very similar data inside, and differ primarily in metadata. Very roughly, one can think of an FLV file as a subset of a SWF file.
>
> Therefore, one can easily transcode from SWF to FLV and back without much work apart from fiddling with headers and the like.
>
> WARNINGs:
>
> - This does not work on any old SWF! It has to be a video/audio-dominated SWF.
>     Don't be surprised if it fails to extract content from some arbitrary SWF you built or download.
>     In particular, it does not handle vector animation.
> - Supports Flash MX and Flash 8 video (that is, Sorenson H.263 and On2 VP6.2 respectively). Flash screen video and VP6 with alpha are both untested but might work.
> - Supports MP3 audio. Other audio formats are untested but might work.
> - Does not support multiple video or audio streams in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

[FormatFactory](http://www.formatoz.com/index.html) might be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in other question, but an useful tool (to be combined with , for example VirtualDub, etc) is http://swftools.org

Answer (score 0):

SUPER is super (http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html), as suggestioned by Mehper C. Palavuzlar!!!

But also you have the last codecs to be allowed to convert to some (other) filetypes. Then download K-Lite Mega Codec Pack.